# В jupyter !pwd отображается вот это

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Переводится как "pwd" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

В ОС `Windows` используется другая команда вместо линуксовой `pwd` для определения текущего каталога - `cd` без аргументов, так что наберите в `Jupyter Notebook`:

```
!cd
```